# Where can I download upref version 2.04?

Tags: cross-referencing

From [this PDF](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/amslatex/classes/upref.pdf), it looks as if the current version of `upref` is 2.04, but [the version on CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/upref) is 2.01. Where can I download version 2.04?

`upref` version 2.01 does not seem to handle italic corrections properly when the `hyperref` package is used; is this fixed in version 2.04?

Comment: I mailed barbara to ask her:-)

Comment: The newer version has a command added that explicitly handles italic corrections when `hyperref` is loaded. So certainly that problem was at least addressed, and probably corrected. It is not hard to create an updated style file by just copying the code lines in `upref.pdf` to a renamed `.sty` file, and it seems to work.

Comment: Barbara is checking what happened to the release process, will report here later....

Comment: @Dan, I tried that, and it did seem to work, but I was hoping to have my MiKTeX automatically download the "official" current version, just to be safe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`upref` version 2.04 was uploaded to ctan in a repackaged `amsclass` collection on
6 august 2014.  (somehow the older version was mistakenly included in the previous
bundle.)

the ctan catalog has not yet been updated to show the change; i have sent a message to the
ctan maintainers asking for that to be corrected.

apologies for the delay in notification.